# Cannot add instances to Active Directory on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to create a private active directory domain ('addemo.com') using windows server 2012 r2 and add some ec2 instances to it.

I have already created the instances on the same VPC (and subnet), promoted one of them to be the domain controller and I have also allowed the necessary exceptions to my security group and firewall (currently, I am accepting all traffic on the security group and I disabled the Windows firewall, in order to be sure that I am not facing a security constraint).

I can ping between VMs, but I cannot add any of the remaining instances to my Active Directory domain. It says that the Domain Controller for the domain 'addemo.com' cannot be contacted.

I think this issue is happening because I am missing how to configure the DNS on my VPC, but I am still not sure about that. Do you know what I might be missing on this architecture?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the security group. AD requires certain ports be opened.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I will try to be clear on this subject. Currently, I disabled Windows FIrewall and opened all traffic on the security group in order to be sure that my problem is not related to security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, all I needed to do was set (for each new EC2 instance to be added to the active directory) the internal ip address of the domain controller as the primary DNS and the AWS DNS (it was the one added by default by the DHCP configuration on my VPC) as the secondary DNS.